# Why isn't NSubstitute.Return called?

Tags: c#, .net, nsubstitute

I'm using [NSubstitute](https://nsubstitute.github.io/) in an integration test by wrapping a real implementation with a mock, like this:

```
var realRepository = container.Get<IRepository>();
var proxyRepository = Substitute.For<IRepository>();

proxyRepository
    .When(repo => repo.InsertValueForEntity(Arg.Any<int>(), Arg.Any<ValueForEntity>())
    .Do(callInfo => realRepository
        .InsertValueForEntity((int)callInfo.Args()[0], (ValueForEntity)callInfo.Args()[1]));

proxyRepository
    .GetValueForEntity(Arg.Any<int>())
    .Returns(callInfo => realRepository
        .GetValueForEntity((int)callInfo.Args()[0]));

// assume these parameters are defined elsewhere
var factory = new EntityFactory(mock1, realDependency, mock2, proxyRepository);
var entity = factory.CreateEntity(/* args */); // <-- this is where proxyRepository.GetValueForEntity() should be called

proxyRepository.Received().InsertValueForEntity(entity.Id, dummyValue);
proxyRepository.Received().GetValueForEntity(Arg.Is(entity.Id));
Assert.That(entity.Value, Is.EqualTo(dummyValue));
```

What's strange to me about this is that I have another test using the `.When().Do()` technique like this, and it works just fine.  And indeed it appears that the configuration for `InsertValueForEntity` works here also.  However, the configuration for `GetValueForEntity` is *not* working, and I don't understand why.  I put a breakpoint in the lambda and it never hits.

Is there something tricky about substitutes that I'm missing here?

Comment: In the code above you instantiate `entity` but what is the value of `dummyValue`? Is it possible that with this being `null` the lambda cannot infer the type to `ValueForEntity`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not seem any obvious problem with the example code, so I am guessing it is an issue with some of the code not shown. Is it possible to post a runnable version that illustrates the problem? I also suggest adding [NSubstitute.Analyzers](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/nsubstitute-analysers/) to your project as it can help detect issues that sometimes causing confusing test behaviour.

Here's a simplified version that demonstrates everything working correctly. If it is possible to modify this to reproduce the problem that would be really helpful!

First, some supporting types:

```
public interface IRepository {
    ValueForEntity GetValueForEntity(int v);
    void InsertValueForEntity(int v, ValueForEntity valueForEntity);
}

public class RealRepository : IRepository {
    private readonly IDictionary<int, ValueForEntity> data = new Dictionary<int, ValueForEntity>();
    public ValueForEntity GetValueForEntity(int v) => data[v];
    public void InsertValueForEntity(int v, ValueForEntity valueForEntity) => data[v] = valueForEntity;           
}

public class ValueForEntity {
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Then a rough approximation of the subject being tested:

```
public class EntityFactory {
    private readonly IRepository repo;
    public EntityFactory(IRepository repo) => this.repo = repo;
    public ValueForEntity CreateEntity(int id) {
        repo.InsertValueForEntity(id, new ValueForEntity { Id = id });
        return repo.GetValueForEntity(id);
    }
}
```

Finally, here's a passing version of the posted test (I had XUnit rather than NUnit handy so changed the assertion and test attribute accordingly):

```
[Fact]
public void Example() {
    var realRepository = new RealRepository();
    var proxyRepository = Substitute.For<IRepository>();

    proxyRepository
        .When(repo => repo.InsertValueForEntity(Arg.Any<int>(), Arg.Any<ValueForEntity>()))
        .Do(callInfo => realRepository
            .InsertValueForEntity((int)callInfo.Args()[0], (ValueForEntity)callInfo.Args()[1]));

    proxyRepository
        .GetValueForEntity(Arg.Any<int>())
        .Returns(callInfo => realRepository
            .GetValueForEntity((int)callInfo.Args()[0]));

    var factory = new EntityFactory(proxyRepository);
    var entity = factory.CreateEntity(42 /* args */); 

    proxyRepository.Received().InsertValueForEntity(entity.Id, Arg.Any<ValueForEntity>());
    proxyRepository.Received().GetValueForEntity(Arg.Is(entity.Id));
    Assert.Equal(42, entity.Id);
}
```

I know the types don't exactly match, but hopefully you can use this working example to find out the main difference that is causing problems in your fixture.

As an aside, is it worth using a substitute at all here if you could just use `realRepository`?

Comment: Thanks for this detailed response.  I did consider just omitting the substitute for this repository because I'm only using it to assert the behavior of the type under test, but now I have a problem to solve and it's hard to let go!

Comment: I know the feeling! Good luck on your quest for the solution! :)

Comment: well it turns out my test is actually broken, not NSubstitute.  I added a direct call to `proxyRepository.GetValueForEntity(entity.Id)` right before calling `factory.CreateEntity()` (in the real code, not this translated example).  The proxy works just fine, breakpoint hit, etc.  It appears the real code was actually not calling the proxy like I thought it was.

In other words... _the test did exactly what it was supposed to do_ :-)

Comment: Glad to hear you got it sorted! :)